# How to stop side menu toggle at body click in ionicframwork?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

How to stop side menu toggle at body click in ionicframwork ?

## I want menu toggle only at header button click not any where were click of whole page .

Answer (score 0):

For this, you should forget to use Ionic menu directive, and write your own directive with you own menu.